# How do I determine the number of changed files and changed lines per file type in a remote gitlab repository

Tags: git, jenkins, github, continuous-integration, gitlab

Please,How do I determine the number of changed files and changed lines per file type, per time window, in a remote gitlab repository

The follows queries git and fetches the changed files and within a window i.e. 2 week sprint. Then, I manually read the files to determine the number of files in the file.

But, I will appreciate help with a command to determine the number of files changed per file type and the number of changed lines per file type e.g. java, xml, jsp etc

$ git whatchanged --since '15/03/2018' --until '29/03/2018' --oneline --name-only --pretty=format: -- *.js *.java | sort | uniq >> changedlist.txt

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git diff --numstat --shortstat` to get the stats that you are after per file. Or just `git diff --stat`

You can use `git log --since="2018-04-12" --until="2018-04-15" --oneline` to get the commit IDs between your date range.

So with these two tools you can generate a command line note: you are better off doing this in a script, but if it must be in one line then...

`git log --since="2018-04-12" --until="2018-04-15" --oneline | awk '{print $1}' | sed -e 1b -e '$!d' | awk '{cmd = $0 ".." cmd} END{print "git diff --numstat --shortstat " substr(cmd, 1, length(cmd)-2)}'`

Will give you a command something like: `git diff --numstat <start_commit>..<end_commit>`. Let me break that down a bit:

- `git log --since="2018-04-12" --until="2018-04-15" --oneline` gets you a list of all the commits between your date range with the commit short ID at the start of each line.
- `| awk '{print $1}'` - Takes the first item in each line (the commit short ID)
- `| sed -e 1b -e '$!d'` - Takes the first and list element only
- `| awk '{cmd = $0 ".." cmd}` - concats the list (of two elements) with comma separation and stores it in variable cmd (e.g. `hash1..hash2..`
- `END{print "git diff --numstat --shortstat " substr(cmd, 1, length(cmd)-2)}'` - prints `git diff --numstat` followed by your cmd minus the last two commas

So with your generated command `git diff --numstat --shortstat <start_commit>..<end_commit>` you get an output like:

`2       2       .gitignore
18      0       main.cpp
36      0       state_machine.cpp
84      0       state_machine.h
15      0       state_machine.pro
11      0       state_middle.cpp
11      0       state_middle.h
24      0       state_start.cpp
12      0       state_start.h
 9 files changed, 213 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)`

Where the numbers mean lines added (first column) list deleted (second column) and your summary of files is at the bottom.

**Note** There are a million ways to do this really, I am sure there is a more efficient sed way, but I am not great with sed. But also there are very many ways to take this summary and whittle it down further. E.g. if you wanted the add/delete line count for .cpp files only then you would format that output again with further awk/sed scripting...

Comment: Thanks so much. I ran (1) git log --since etc (2) git diff --numstat --shortstat 5e32390..b3237c1 -- *.jsp *.js *.java *.xml  [I added the extensions to filter by file type] . I got total file counts, insertions and deletions across all file types (3) I ran the same cmd per file type e.g. git diff --numstat --shortstat 5e32390..b3237c1 -- *.jsp [for JSP diff stats], then repeated for JS and Java. Two questions, (1) Is my approach for gathering stats per file type right? Should file type filtering be done in the first cmd i.e. git log ? (2) What will d bash script for this look like? Thankssss

Comment: (3) How do I update the script, if I wanted only the footer (e.g. 9 files changed, 213 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)). When gathering  across-file-type totals and per-file-type totals stats? Thanks. Ola

Comment: @olatom 1. If it works... yes!, why not?, as I said there are many many ways to do this. I am sure there is more efficient, but so long as it occurs in a reasonable amount of time and its maintainable/readable then its all good : )   2. I am sorry I don't understand... everything you run on the command line can be put into a bash script - so just copy paste what you want into a bash script : ) .... if you have specific issues with the script then post as another question, np : )

Comment: 3. If you just want the summary only use `git diff --shortstat <start_commit>..<end_commit> -- *.jsp` for example

Comment: Perfect, you have made my weekend. Thanks a million.

Comment: @olatom ..lol - well, it is only just still the weekend so you just made it : ))

Comment: Hello, please which branch does git log query? I cloned the develop branch, but I really need git log to query only the develop branch, NOT the master or feature branches.

Comment: I tried $ git log origin/develop and the number of files changed was reduced from 1457 to 1173. This concerns me, 284 files difference. I guess, my original git log was adding files changed from all branches for the repos? Right?

Comment: @olatom If you want all branches then use `git log [options] --all`, for a log of the current branch only: `git log [options]`, for a log of some specific branch (e.g. master): `git log [options] master`, or for the remote: `git log [options] origin/master` : )

Comment: Wow, you are still there for me. Thanks. I want only origin/develop and I used: git log origin/develop --since="2018-04-12" --until="2018-04-15" --oneline | awk '{print $1}' | sed -e 1b -e '$!d' | awk '{cmd = $0 ".." cmd} END{print "git diff --numstat --shortstat " substr(cmd, 1, length(cmd)-2)}' .  What is [options] ?

Comment: @olatom  haha, well, I think you get what you give on this site : )  ... so [options] was just my way of saying `...etc...` for all the other options e.g. `--since="..." --until=.... so on` : )

Comment: @olatom - you don't like my answer anymore and un-ticked it? : (

Comment: Top Man. You have been very helpful. Saved my Job! Your answer is 200% accepted!